# Rare effect with ImageView Android, Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: android, imageview, titanium, appcelerator

So, we developed an app using titanium appcelerator, there is a problem when using images in a ImageView, in the image we can see certain waves, a rare effect.

With ImageView

[image]

Now the temporary solution that was found was to give a backgroundImage to View

With View

[image]

But we have a problem when using multiple View to display images, the app crashed due to lack of memory

Someone had the same problem and found how to fix it?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

From the provided images it looks like this: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-6908

So if you are using a PNG try to use a JPG or convert the PNG to 16bit.

You can also set the pixelFormat of the Window on Android. Some testcode is provided in this ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-4104
`win.setWindowPixelFormat(Ti.UI.Android.PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888);`

Comment: Thanks for your repply, but this was not the case. We solve it by putting images into a WebView. The actual imageView is compressing the image. I dunno why